# How to convert a series into an index of another series, aligned by their indexes

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have this series:

```
dealer      certificate_status brand_kia 
aeropuerto      NO               False     22 days
                                 True      29 days
Galerías         SI              False     59 days
                 NO              False     34 days
```

And I have another series:

```
dealer
aeropuerto    36 days
Galerías      41 days
```

How can I place the values of the last series as an index of the first series, but with an average name.
It would be like this:

```
dealer       average     certificate_status    brand_kia 
aeropuerto    36 days           NO              False     22 days
                                                True      29 days
Galerías      41 ays            SI              False     59 days
                                NO              False     34 days
```

It is possible to make this movement. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) fo columns from `MultiIndex`, then [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) new column to position 1 by [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) and last [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `Multiindex` with `squeeze` for convert one column `df` to `Series`:

```
s = s.reset_index()
s.insert(1, 'average', s['dealer'].replace(s1))
s = s.set_index(['dealer','average','certificate_status','brand_kia']).squeeze()
print (s)
dealer      average  certificate_status  brand_kia
aeropuerto  36 days  NO                  False        22 days
                                         True         29 days
Galerias    41 days  SI                  False        59 days
                     NO                  False        34 days
Name: dt, dtype: object
```

Or you can create new `MultiIndex` by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) and [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) and assign back:

```
lvl1 = s.index.get_level_values(0)
lvl2 = s.index.get_level_values(1)
lvl3 = s.index.get_level_values(2)

lvl = pd.Series(lvl1).replace(s1).values

s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([lvl1, lvl, lvl2, lvl3],
                         names=['dealer','average','certificate_status','brand_kia'])
print (s)
dealer      average  certificate_status  brand_kia
aeropuerto  36 days  NO                  False        22 days
                                         True         29 days
Galerias    41 days  SI                  False        59 days
                     NO                  False        34 days
Name: dt, dtype: object
```